# Trying to define a set path for FileDialog

Tags: excel, vba

Hi there I am trying to import a `.txt` file via `FileDialog` using the following code utilizing query tables. My problem is that I cannot define the path which the `FileDialog` brings up, it just opens up the generic `"Documents\Excel folder"`. How would I define a path that this dialog opens up? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub ImportTextFile()
Dim fName As FileDialog, LastRow As Long

Set fName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
fName.InitialFileName = "\\olscmesf003\gcm_emea\TCU_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\Pointsec for PC  Web RH\2017\"
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
        Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow))
            .Name = "sample"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "" & Chr(10) & ""
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please verify the path in `InitialFileName`? According to this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/filedialog-initialfilename-property-office), specifying `InitialFileName` would work as long as the path is valid.

Comment: To clarify: I am not trying to import a predefined file, I just want to open up a folder via FileDalog and Then have the user select the file to import (which is a text file with varying name) Don't know if it  helps. I get the following error message btw: `"Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range. Check to make sure this text file has not been moved or renamed, then try the refresh again."'`

Comment: Are you trying to use the folderpath in the query without the filename added to it? Here Connection:="TEXT;" & fName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is because you haven't specified the file along with the folder path in the query connection string

Quoting from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/querytablesadd-using-a-user-defined-connection/766135e1-6a76-47bb-9834-c1fe37ac862e?auth=1) syntax is.....

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\Test.TXT", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        ... Blah
End With
```

You have

`Connection:="TEXT;" & fName`  where fName is

```
"\\olscmesf003\gcm_emea\TCU_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\Pointsec for PC  Web RH\2017\"
```

i.e. has no filename associated.

If you use the filedialog object 
`Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` you can collect the file selected and put it in a variable.

E.g.  `FileName = .SelectedItems(1)`

```
Sub Main()
'https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/folders-file-handling/ ''example layout taken from here.

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileChosen As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
    Dim fd As FileDialog

    'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box. This allows you to capture the selected item.
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
    With fd

         'Set initial folder to open to
        .InitialFileName = "\\olscmesf003\gcm_emea\TCU_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\Pointsec for PC  Web RH\2017\"

        'Set the Folder View
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons

        'Set the caption of the dialog box,
        .Title = "Please select a WebRHLog file"

        'Allow only one file to be selected
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        'Set the filter
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text files", "*.txt"   'Not sure anything other than extension can be used as filter

        fileChosen = .Show

        If fileChosen <> -1 Then

           'No file selected/ Clicked on CANCEL
            MsgBox "No file selected"
            Exit Sub

        Else
           'capture name and complete path of file chosen
           fileName = .SelectedItems(1)

        End If

    End With

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fileName, _
        Destination:=Range("A" & lastRow))
            .Name = "sample"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "" & Chr(10) & ""
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi that seems like a good point, however I deliberately don't want to specify a file, just have the folder opened up and the user select a text file found in that folder. The text file itself has varying names which cannot be pre-defined.

Comment: I could do something like this `fName.InitialFileName = "\\olscmesf003\gcm_emea\TCU_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\Pointsec for PC  Web RH\2017\test\test\" * WebRHLogs * ""` but I get Type mismatch, I could define a part of the file I am trying to import (it contains `"*WebRHLogs*"` and forego the file selection)

Comment: the .InitialFileName is setting the default folder to open at. The filedialog object has a property .SelectedItems that capture the file which is then selected. If you haven't enabled multiselect then .SelectedItems(1) will capture the selection made i.e. the filename.

Comment: Oh god I know I'm a pain, but I just don't get it. Could you please update your answer with my code modified according to your suggestion? I tried putting Filename=.SelectedItems(1) and rename fName to fPath to no avail.

Comment: The filename looks like this: `WebRHLogs-20171207-10235.txt` where the date varies, and the 5 digit number in the end is randomly generated. However on Mondays there are three files (for the weekends) so sometimes there are multiple files that need to be imported/processed individually.

Comment: Just tested it, works beautifully! Thank you so much.